# Celling fan go slow

Tags: electrical

Folks, I need technical help. I bought some electric funs from the US to Ghana to be installed in my house. I have it running on a stepdown 220V/50w to 110V transformer. All the electrical equipment in the house including Fridges run well on the transformer except the fans that run very slow. What is going on here?

Comment: Show us the name plate of the fan motor. It should specify power required by the fan. I suspect your step down transformer is low power type and overloaded by the fan.

Answer (score 2):

AC motor speed is based on the frequency of the power. A US based motor will be designed around 60Hz, Ghana is 50Hz, so all AC motors will spin at 5/6th the speed they were designed for. They will also provide less torque, so will run at an increased "slip", meaning even lower speed and they will run hotter.

Some small portable appliances use what are called "universal motors" that are AC/DC and less dependent upon frequency so you may not notice a difference, things like blenders, vacuum cleaners, hair driers etc.. But your fans will run slower and your fridge compressor motor will run, but probably fail earlier than normal due to the excess thermal stress on the motors. Did you check on the appropriateness of bringing electrical devices over from the US? It's usually not worth it.